# How to deal with blocking commands in systemd service ExecStartPre lines?

Tags: systemd, backup, openvpn, btrfs, systemd-unit

Before my backup program (btrbk) can send its backup to my server, I need to open a VPN connection. Opening up the VPN connection by hand works perfectly fine, by invoking

```
openvpn --config VPNConfig.ovpn
```

I now created a systemd service (which is triggered daily by a systemd time) that is supposed to start the backup.
As a prerequisite, it therefore should connect to the VPN, therefore have a

```
ExecStartPre=openvpn --config VPNConfig.ovpn
```

line in the service file. Unfortunately however, this openvpn call is blocking, therefore is also blocking the actual backup process from being executed.

What would be the best way to workaround that issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ExecStartPre=`, you should create a separate service for the OpenVPN connection, specify it should start `Before=` your backup service, and with a dependency to it according to your needs:

If you want the VPN connection to start for the backup *and stop after the backup is done*, you could declare the VPN service be a `PartOf=` your backup service.

If the VPN can/should be left running after the backup is done, you could specify the VPN service as `RequiredBy=` the backup service.

If your VPN solution for the backup needs to be changed later, you could then just rewrite or replace the VPN service unit without touching the actual backup unit or its timer.

You would then omit the common `WantedBy=multi-user.target` from the VPN service, so the only way it would be started would be either by the dependency or by an explicit `systemctl start` command.

And to paraphrase Aperture Science's ad copy, *now you're thinking with units.*

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed way better.
Went with this now and it works like a charm.